# How To publish my own library which is currently generated android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I follow the following steps and generated .aar file and i also use this library in my another project but how to make global publish.

[Steps to generate library](http://dominoc925.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-create-and-use-android-archive.html)

Comment: There're quite some steps to go through. In general is 1) create an account on bintray; 2) create some auth_keys; 3) add some lines to your gradle; 4) run a gradle command to upload the library; 5) on bintray panel, transfer the uploaded files to jcenter. You can read all about it in this very nicely detailed tutorial http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Comment: hello, 
@Budius I have tried this but i can't publish through this steps.

Comment: That's how I do on all libraries I created. I suggest to read it carefully, and create a new question (or update this one here), with exact which part of it it's not working for you.

Comment: Part 3 : Enable Auto Signing in Bintray @Budius

Comment: that is standard process of creating signing key. If you're having trouble with that I suggest you to: 1) Google on how to do it; 2) if you're stuck on some part ask a **specific** question about the specific issue you're having.